# Ruby's Array Combination Method

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am going through the problems on Ruby Monk's Ruby Primer.

Problem Statement
Given a 3 or 4 digit number with distinct digits, return a sorted array of all the unique numbers that can be formed with those digits.
Example:
Given: 123
Return: [123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321]

I thought that the Array#combination method would do the trick. My code looks like this:

```
def number_shuffle(number)
  # take integer and turn it into an array of digits
  digits = Array.new

  number.to_s.split('').each do |element|
    digits << element.to_i
  end

  # shuffle the elements
  return digits.combination(digits.length).to_a
end

puts number_shuffle(123)
```

But the code above returns:

```
1
2
3
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I thought the documentation made it clear:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-combination

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For `number = 123`, you compute `[1,2,3].combination(3).to_a => [[1,2,3]]` and `puts [[1,2,3]]` will print `1`, `2` and `3` on successive lines. By contrast, `p [[1,2,3]]` prints `[[1, 2, 3]]` on one line. You get this result because every array `a` has only one combination of size `a.size`, namely `a`, so `[a]` is returned.  On the other hand, `[1,2,3].combination(1).to_a => [[1], [2], [3]]` and `[1,2,3].combination(2) => [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]`. I believe you are aware that you need to use `permutation` rather than `combination`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Array#combination`, you want [`Array#permutation`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation):

```
number = 123
number.to_s.split('').permutation.map(&:join).uniq.sort
# => ["123", "132", "213", "231", "312", "321"]

number = 122
number.to_s.split('').permutation.map(&:join).uniq.sort
# => ["122", "212", "221"]
```

Comment: Thanks guys, but now I don't understand what the combination methods does.

Comment: See http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html . Also, when selecting a solution, what should the result be when `number = 122`?

Comment: The best way to understand the difference between `combinations` and `permuations` is to just evaluate an array both ways and see what you get: `[1,2,3].combination(2).to_a => [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]`, `[1,2,3].permutation(2).to_a => [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2]]`. You see that for the combination `[1, 2]` there are two permutations `[1, 2]` and `[2, 1]`.  For the combination `[1,2,4]` from `[1,2,3,4].combination(3).to_a` there are six (3x2) permutations: `[1,2,4]`, `[1,4,2]`, `[2,1,4]`, `[2,4,1]`,  `[4,1,2]` and `[4,2,1]`

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I understand what you mean from a mathematical standpoint, but the code in my original post returns 1, 2, 3, and no combinations at all. There's something still missing there.

Comment: @user245185 `[1,2,3].combination(3).to_a # => [[1, 2, 3]]`. Compare this with `[1,2,3].combination(2).to_a # => [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]`. In the first case, there is only 1 combination that is 3 elements long. In the second case, there are 3 combinations that are 2 elements long.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the permutations of the character array using [`Array#permutation`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation):

```
def number_shuffle(number)
  number.to_s.chars.permutation.map { |x| x.join.to_i }.sort
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For the ruby monk question what u need is the Array.permutations. Array.permutation(n) is the number of possible arrangements of an array taking n at a time.
[1,2,3] with n = 1 will be 1, 2, 3
[1,2,3] with n = 2 will be [1,2] [2,1] [1,3] [3,1] [2,3] [3,2]

What you need is

```
   Array.permutations(Array.length)
```

**Array.combination(n)** returns the number of unique selections that can be made from the array when taking n objects out of the array.

**for an Array [1,2,3] if n = 1**. You can only take out one element at a time
the possible selections are 1 ,2 and 3.

**for an Array [1,2,3] if n= 2**. You can take out two elements at a time.
the possible selections are [1,2] , [1,3] and [2,3]

**You have given the length of the Array as N (N = Array.Length)**

So in the case of [1,2,3] if n = 3, There is only one way to make a 
selection using all the elements. 
That is [1,2,3]. This is why your code only returns one combination.